# How to use onSaveInstanceState method with Arraylist

Tags: android, state

I have built an ArrayList with an API results. I don`t want it to disappear when a user rotates his phone.

What should I do with onSaveInstanceState?

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);

                    JSONArray searchArray = json.getJSONArray("Search");

                    for (int i = 0; i < searchArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject searchObject = searchArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        String title = searchObject.getString("Title");
                        String type = searchObject.getString("Type");
                        String year = searchObject.getString("Year");
                        String imdbID = searchObject.getString("imdbID");

                        movieList.add(new Movie(title, type, year, imdbID));
```

Comment: use json string and svae it in bundle

Comment: I don`t think i have s json string, i have though json object

Answer (score 10):

Assuming the arrayList you want to keep track of is called `myArrayList`
This code in the activity will serve your purpose :

**For String Array :**

```
ArrayList myArrayList;

//put value of myArrayList in some other method

protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putStringArrayList("myArrayList", myArrayList);
}


protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    myArrayList = savedInstanceState.getStringArrayList("myArrayList");
}
```

**For Custom Object Array :**

Make the objects' class implement the interface `Parcelable` and then add the objects to the `ArrayList`. In your case, make the `Movie` class implement `Parcelable` and add the objects to `movieList`.

Then use the same methods and instead of `putStringArrayList()` use :

```
outState.putParcelableArrayList("movieList", movieList);
```

Similarly, use :

```
movieList = (ArrayList<Movie>) savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList("movieList");
```

in the `onRestoreInstanceState()` method to get the array back.

Comment: Thank you, but i can`t understand what to write instead of  myArrayList  that you mentioned...

Comment: Show us your code. That will help me better answer your question.

Comment: You mentioned that you have created an arraylist. use that arraylist in place of myArrayList.

Comment: Yes, otherwise he has to implement the custom object type as `Parcelable`. and then put the objects in the `ArrayList`.

Then use `outState.putParcelableArrayList()`.

Comment: Not here, edit your original question and put your code there.

Comment: You want to save the movieList i presume? Then implement Parcelable in the Movie class and then follow my answer

Comment: thnx, does that mean that there is no other way but implement Parcelable ?

Comment: I do not know of any other way of saving an `ArrayList`. You can try marking the `ArrayList movieList` as static, and declaring it as a `class variable` though. That will keep the value. You can try that. though I am very skeptical about this method.